# Screen Command - How to leave screen and start it again

Tags: gnu-screen

I have a Python script I have set to run on boot on my Pi (Raspian Jessie).

Running the `screen` command `sudo screen -r wixel` prints the running output of this script. Everything looks good.

Hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> stops the output. But running `sudo screen -r wixel` produces the following...

```
There is no screen to be resumed matching wixel.
```

Now, I'm new to Linux, and perhaps it's by design. But I thought this would take me back into the view of the running script.

It appears as though I'm actually terminating the script altogether.

How is this different to the [Tail](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/utail.htm) command? How can I toggle the view on and off without terminating the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are terminating it.

To disconnect from the screen session press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> followed by <kbd>d</kbd>.

To reconnect to screen session - you need to first get screen session id.

```
screen -list
```

followed by

```
screen -r sessionid
```

Comment: Ctrl-a then d worked, and I can get back with `sudo screen -r wixel` but `screen -list` presents `No Sockets found in /var/run/screen/S-pi.
`

Comment: Not that it matters. I'm happy doing that.

Comment: Then in your case sudo screen -list. Screen creates socket files under /var/run/screen/S-userid directory.  So if your original screen session was created from under root (sudo), then you should be using sudo when trying to list sessions.